# Biometric Authentication on in web applications

Tags: asp.net, authentication, biometrics

Gone through the given post here: [ASP - Biometric Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022306/asp-biometric-authentication)

Want to know how will I achieve biometric thumb authentication with web application, Is their any provider or Biometric Application makers available who will give me the WEB API through which will send user secure data to server which will authenticate the user.

Actually I have started this new not having enough information how this biometric authentication works.

Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer [HTML Based Fingerprint Scanner for Website Login, Web based attendance](http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html)  which can be used for integrating the fingerprint reader with your website. It sends the fingerprint data and comparision score to your server URL in encrypted format.